# How to pass GO_REVISION from upstream pipeline to downstream pipeline in GO-CD?

Tags: go-cd

How to pass GO_REVISION from upstream pipeline to downstream pipeline?

I have four pipelines, A, B and C pipelines built application trigger by same git and their version tag in GO_REVISION.

The pipeline D use for deployment and it's materials are A, B and C.

However, I don't know how to share the GO_REVISION from the upstream pipeline  (A/B/C) to D.

```
              +--->Pipeline A +
              |               |
GIT (Material)+--->Pipeline B +------>Pipeline D (How get upstream GO_REVISION)
              |               |
              +--->Pipeline C +
```

Comment: Maybe write it to a file in one of the upstream pipelines and fetch it as a material in the downstream pipeline

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you have any use case with the repository you should make GIT (Material) as a dependent material for Pipeline-D.

Otherwise, You can make GO_REVISION as a label for any of the upstream pipeline (let's set for pipeline A) and access environment variable ${GO_DEPENDENCY_LABEL_A} in pipeline-D which should hold GO_REVISION.
[Image : Setting Pipeline-A label to hold GO_REVISION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPEV8.png)

In the above image changing label from ${material_name} to ${material_name[:6]} should take only first 6 letters from SHA.

[Image : Accessing GO_REVISION in Pipeline D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNgJL.png)

Generally this kind of approach is used if you want to represent the builds using revision.

Another approach would be writing it to a file in one of the upstream pipelines and fetch it in the downstream pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting A,B and C into a single pipeline.

ABC can run in parallel as tasks. Why do I say this - because it will ensure ABC always build off the same Git commit. If ABC are separate pipelines, there is a chance of a race condition (e.g. waiting for an agent, failed build etc.) GoCD will flag an warning if ABC are on different revisions of source. But simple is best.

That done, getting the revision to D is staightforward via the pipline label.

However. I *always* write version information to the built artifacts in flat files. The extra meta-data makes it possible to guarantee audit-ability of the code on the production end. You should also inject the version information into the application user interface (if it has one).